# How to access a controller from multiple screens - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, controller

Let's say I created a `ScrollController` in a `statefullWidget` like so:

```dart
  late ScrollController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = ScrollController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Using this controller indside the widget is easy.
But, if I want to access that controller from another screen, I have to pass it as a parameter maybe like so:

```dart
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/another-screen', arguments: controller);
```

But, **What if the screens are totally independent?** (I can't pass it as an argument) I thought of using `Provider` to globally provide the controller. But now, I can't dispose it.

Comment: Provider is a good option to do this. Why can't you dispose it? You either let Provider handle disposing for you using `Provider()` constructor, or pass an existing value that you will dispose of yourself when you decide using `Provider.value()` constructor. Also what does it mean if the screens are independent? Then do you really want to share the same controller? Please elaborate

Comment: `what does it mean if the screens are independent?` : 2 screens where no one take to the other. Let's say having a home screen that leads to both those screens.

`Then do you really want to share the same controller?` : I want to controll the scrolling in those screens with the same controller so that I have the same behavior.

`Provider is a good option to do this. Why can't you dispose it?` : Can you please talk more on how the provider is disposed? (seems it will be disposed automatically? or do I have to explicitly dispose it?)

Comment: Then you should maintain your own value and decide when to dispose of it. You will still be able to fetch it when you want in either screen. Then dispose of it at your own will

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can you take a look at my previous comment I added 2 more questions.

Comment: If you use `Provider()` widget, you give it a `create: () => ScrollController()` method, which it will use to create a new instance when it needs, and it will destroy it automatically. If you want to control when to dispose, use the `Provider.value()` constructor instead, which accepts `value: scrollController` argument instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Consider using riverpod

First create a State Notifier provider that has the scroll controller  as its state
Here you can put any logic related to him , and you can dispose him by ovveriding the dispose method of State Notifier

```dart
class GlobalScrollController extends StateNotifier<ScrollController> {
      GlobalScrollController() : super(ScrollController());
 
      @override
      void dispose() {
        state.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    }
    
    final globalScrollControllerProvider =
        StateNotifierProvider<GlobalScrollController, ScrollController>(
            (ref) => GlobalScrollController());
```

#### Consume The Provider Where you want to use it Like This

```dart
  class Example extends ConsumerWidget {
      const Example({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
        final scrollController = ref.watch(globalScrollControllerProvider);
    
        return Scaffold(
          body: ListView(
            controller: scrollController,
          ....
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

And you can optimize this further more

Answer (score 1):

try to add on global  **late ScrollController controller;**
and then initialise that variable
you can declare on main.dart **late ScrollController controller;**